# Android Chrome WebView.draw(canvas) does not draw HTML 5 canvas

Tags: android, android-webview, chromium

I am using the method `WebView.draw(android.graphics.Canvas)` for writing the web view content to a `Surface` rendered using OpenGL.

Since the last version of Google Chrome (Chrome 76.0.3809.89), the HTML 5 canvas that are present in the HTML page are not drawn.

As anything changed and what should I modify in my code to keep it working with the latest Chrome version?